# Cannot get @Html.RouteLink on Intellisense

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-2

Am I missing a namespace import? Or using the wrong razor version? Or is it simply a syntax error? When I type "@Html." I do not get the RouteLink function in Visual Studio.

edit: I don't know if this helps anyone, I'm following a tutorial where the author is typing "@Url.RouteUrl" and I wouldn't get that in intellisense either. Instead i did "var url = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(Context.Request.RequestContext);" and then found the RouteUrl function through the url variable

[image: Cannot find RouteLink on intellisense]

Comment: First of all, post a code example from where you're trying to call `@Html.RouteLink()`. Second, check your Web.config and make sure that the proper frameworks are present.

Comment: I have the most simple cshtml file and trying to type "@Html." in the body tag. I wish I could check the web.config myself, I have no idea what to look out for.

Comment: @user2765861 - what version of visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this as the 1st line in your Login.cshtml:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
```

Alternatively, check make sure your web.config has this:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    ...
    <pages ...>
      <namespaces>
        ...
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        ...
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but maybe useful for others.

I sort it this way:

1. Close VS
2. Delete .suo file from the solution folder.
3. Open project again.

Intellisense should be available again.